# Right way to create tables in public schema in Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have worked on PostgreSQL, which has a concept of public schema. By default all objects goes into public schema, if no schema is defined explicitly. This allows all the users in that database to access all objects in public schema.

I want to know what is the equivalent of this in Oracle DB. How do I create objects using ADMIN user and make them available to all the users in that db. Currently, objects created using ADMIN are available to ADMIN user only. We have to explicitly grant permissions to other users to objects in ADMIN schema.

Answer (score 3):

> We have to explicitly grant permissions to other users to objects in ADMIN schema.

Exactly, that's how Oracle works.

Though, you don't have to do it "manually". A good option is to create a **role**, then grant privileges on tables to that role, and - finally - grant role to every user you want. What's good in it? If new user is created, just grant the same role to it and everything *works*.

Also, you can write a script to do the job for you. If you're connected as ADMIN, then e.g.

```
SQL> begin
  2    for cur_r in (select table_name from user_tables) loop
  3      execute immediate 'grant select on ' || cur_r.table_name ||' to admin_role';
  4    end loop;
  5  end;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

In a matter of *seconds* everything is done.

Comment: Also, add a command to your app to switch to required schema.
In your case: alter session set current_schema=ADMIN;

Comment: I will have to run this script every time I create a new table or object. Is there a way I can give permission to the whole schema?

Comment: There's none, Prometheus. But, if a new table is created, it is a simple task to grant it (separately) to the role: `grant select on my_new_table to admin_role`. As soon as it finishes (and that's *instantly*), all users - who were granted that role - can access data in that table.